# Создание документации к архиву

Tags: документация

Подскажите лучший способ для создания документации к моему архиву.
Исходные данные: 
есть проект, в котором беспорядочно лежит куча всяких классов (написанных на Java , IDE - IDEA, OS Windows),  каждый класс — отдельный файл, на всякий случай я в шапке каждого класса оставлял такой шаблон:

```
/**
 * Описание …
 * @version 2.1
*/
```

в этих классах находятся примеры, функции, просто куски кода, т. е. Какае-то оригинальные решения, которые мне где-либо попадались или сам что-то запиливал, общем по какой-то причине я решил его сохранить. Изначально это не задумывалось как архив, поэтому, в настоящий момент и похоже больше на мусорную свалку. Пока этих классов было 10-50, проблем особо не вызывало, а когда их кол-во перевалило за 100 я стал задумываться как бы мне это все упорядочить.
Вопрос:
Подскажите лучший способ как можно это все упорядочить.
Т.е. какую лучше использовать для этого софтину (только желательно бесплатную) Если надо что-то доработать под нее — не вопрос. 
Что я хочу на выходе: 
Что бы было какое-то дерево (или папки с подпапками или еще что-то), т. е. Все это должно быть распределено по каким то темам (подтемам и т. д.), конечный список ( конкретный класс, метод и т. д.) должен иметь название на русском и при его выборе (причем не закрывая основного меню или дерева) должно где-то рядом появляться его полное описание. Так же хотелось, что бы был поиск по этим названием, а еще лучше и по описанию.

PS: Программ и способов для создания документации очень много, юзать каждую времени не хватит, попробовал использовать Javadoc – он отказывается отображать текст на русском, попробовал Doxygen – он выводит название всех классов (а мне надо, что бы были мои названия на русском) и чтобы посмотреть описание конкретного класса надо провалиться в него, что не очень удобно, мне надо, чтобы при это не закрывалось основное дерево (меню), т. е. Чтобы можно было быстро пробежаться по дереву и найти, то что нужно.
Что посоветуете лучше использовать для этого?

Comment: Doxygen может сделать то, что Вам нужно (если я Вас правильно понял, конечно :) ). Но для этого нужно садиться, и прописывать документирующие комментарии в коде, которые будут содержать всю ту информацию ,что Вы хотите увидеть. И названия на русском, и разбиения по темам - все это можно реализовать. Если ли что-то, что может сделать это автоматом.... А как может софтина определить, на какие темы и как разбить Ваш архив?

Comment: Я выше описал, что мне не понравилось в Doxygen - возможно я действительно с ним плохо знаком. но вы уверены, что все эти проблемы можно в нем решить. С разбивкой по темам - это уже сложнее для автомата, пока, что только если разбивать в проекте по пакетам. Но можно ли к ним делать комменты?

Comment: Да, я прочитал, что Вам не понравилось. Потому и написал свой комментарий, что, на мой взгляд, Вы могли бы решить свои проблемы с помощью Doxygen, если у Вас будет время и желание покопаться в документации на него. Там можно делать группы сущностей (не обязательно классов, но и отдельных методов, при желании), подгруппы в них, делать комменты к ним любой степени подробности, с разбивкой на параграфы, выделением важного, ссылкой на другие части документации и внешние ресурсы, вставлять таблицы, диаграммы зависимостей (графы вызовов и наследования). Инструмент весьма гибкий, если покопаться.

Comment: Стандартные разделы типа Классы, Файлы, Пространства имен можно убрать, переставить, переименовать, их части тоже можно менять местами, переименовывать и убирать, Можно добавлять какие-то свои разделы, можно сделать какое-то общее описание ко всему архиву в целом ,с собственным оглавлением и ссылками и т.п.